# Android Listview shuffle image load from the net and local

Tags: android, image, listview, load, shuffle

I've a problem with a listview and shuffle image.

Premise: I know that the cells/rows are re-used (recycled)

My cell is made up of an image and some textview (to simplify we suppose, only one image and only one tetxview)

if the image is present on the net (I know that by a bussines logic...) it's downloaded from the net (correct image); otherwise I put an image from application's bundle (default image)

in this way, i've a shuffle images problem.

Instead, if I load the defualt image always from the net, it's work fine.

My question is: why? why if i load default-image from the net it's ok, but if i load default-image from the app's bundle I've shuffle images problem?

Thanks in advance.

Code of MyAdaper

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {

    final String URL_DEFAULT_IMG_USER="https://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/default.png";

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<MyObject> data;
    LinearLayout l1=null;
    Context context=null;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context,List<MyObject> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_myobject, objects);

        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=objects;
        this.context=context;

        BitmapManagerNoCompressionUser.INSTANCE.setPlaceholder(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                context.getResources(), R.drawable.user));

    }

    //ViewHolder class that hold over ListView Item 
    static class ViewHolder{
            //ImageView image;
            ImageView image;
            TextView displayName;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){                

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_myobject, null);

            holder =new ViewHolder();           

            holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);          
            holder.displayName =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDisplayName);          
            convertView.setTag(R.id.imageViewMyObject, holder.image);           
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textViewDisplayName, holder.displayName);

            //set tag of convertView to the holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);         
        }

        else {          
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();          
            /*  THIS CODE IS IRRELEVANT FOR THE SUFFLE PROBLEM, BUT I DONT'KNOW IF IT IS NECESSARY      
            holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.getTag(R.id.imageViewMyObject);            
            holder.displayName =(TextView) convertView.getTag(R.id.textViewDisplayName);            
            */          
        }       

        holder.image.setTag(position); // This line is important.               

        if(data.get(position).getPathFotoServer()!=null ) {         
            BitmapManagerNoCompressionUser.INSTANCE.loadBitmap(data.get(position).getPathFotoServer(), holder.image, 100,100);          
       } else {         
           BitmapManagerNoCompressionUser.INSTANCE.loadBitmap(URL_DEFAULT_IMG_USER, holder.image, 100,100);   //IT'S OK  
           //holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default); //WITH THIS LINE, SHUFFLE IMAGE PROBLEM
           }       

        holder.displayName.setText((CharSequence) data.get(position).getDisplayName());    

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Code of item_myobject

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/state_item_listview"
    >
     <!-- android:layout_margin="5dp" -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDisplayName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: add the code for sort items in the activity:

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<MyObject>(){
                            public int compare(MyObject s1, MyObject s2) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "s1.getDisplayName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getDisplayName():"+s1.getDisplayName()+" "+s2.getDisplayName());
                                return s1.getDisplayName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getDisplayName());
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: What is **"shuffle image's problem"**?

Comment: I guess the problem is the List object in java is not ordinated, so for example you expect the image at position 4 to be "myimage.png" but it isn't because the list is not ordinated.

Comment: Thansk, I'm sorry: pratically, when you scroll the list, sometimes (random), the default image (loaded from inside the app) is replaced by an image downloaded previously from the net, but belongs another row-cell, but if I load default image always from the net, it's work fine. I hope that's more clear....sorry for my english

Comment: Sorry RedFox, the list is ordered because in the activity, before to call the adapter, i do it (i've update the post). But, If I have a list not-ordered, the problem should be also when i download everithing always from the net, or no?

Answer (score 0):

**This is your problem:**

```
else {         
   BitmapManagerNoCompressionUser.INSTANCE.loadBitmap(URL_DEFAULT_IMG_USER, holder.image, 100,100);   //IT'S OK  
   //holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default); //WITH THIS LINE, SHUFFLE IMAGE PROBLEM
}
```

Image loading from web it is'nt a quick operation, and while it's running, adapter set image to your adapter from it's own cache.

For this situations i use often a viewSwitcher - when i start loading data i show a progress bar while image is loading. For example - here my code:
Explantations
- newsItem is my adapter item which contains image_url call's "pict" and "image" as my bitmap image. Also in newsItem i create an AsyncTask which will load image from url, and after setting an ArrayList to my adapter i've start an asyncTask and show progressBar in display, if picture was downloaded sucessfuly - i show an image.

```
if (newsItem.pict.length() != 0  && 
    !newsItem.isTaskWasStarted() && 
    newsItem.image == null) {
    loadImage(newsItem, viewItem);
} else if (newsItem.image != null) {
    viewItem.image.setImageBitmap(newsItem.image);
    viewItem.flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
} else if (newsItem.pict.length() == 0) {
    viewItem.flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
} else if (newsItem.image == null && newsItem.isTaskWasStarted()) {
    viewItem.flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks whizzzkey, but: with the stament "BitmapManagerNoCompressionUser.INSTANCE...." it's ok, no problem. But with the statement "holder.image.setImageResource..." I've the problem. (this operation is very quickly!)

Comment: @user2968278 Please try to understand - in your if-else statement you trying to get an image from web or wrom resources, right? But you set an image only in "else", in "holder.image.setImageResource", if you are setting image in BitmapManagerNoCompressionUser, you must call adapter.notifyDatasetChaged every time when image has downloaded. Your adapter will using R.drawable.default every time when it get an "else" and other image is'nt downloded yet or adapter has'nt been notified yet that image has dawnloaded

Comment: @user2968278 in other words - if you forget to set any other image in "if" or to notify that image has downloaded - adapter will use a R.drawable.default, so that why i advise  you to use an progress bar - to indicate thats image is downloading now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load images in your listview from server then use android query for performing this, it will manage every thing for you. You don't have to bother for any thing.

[check this link for example with code](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading)